# Bash shortcut for take the variable that exists from many

Tags: bash, if-statement, logic

I've had this question for awhile. In my work that uses bash scripting there are many instances where I have to save a filepath to a variable for use in a later command. We use files with suffixes T1w, T2w, and mask and in many cases we have a preferential file (e.g. T1ws) but, in their absence, will use another file (e.g. T2w). I usually use the following bash syntax to search for the appropriate file and save it to a variable (given I am searching in my current directory):

```
if [ -f xxx_T1w ]; then
  var1=xxx_T1w
elif [ -f xxx_T2w ]; then
  var1=xxx_T2w
fi
```

So ok fine, it works but I was always curious if there was a way in bash to code something like: *If one of two given files exists, take the one that exists, and if both exist, take the first file.*
I'm horrendous at pseudocode but maybe something like:

```
if [ -f file_T1w ] || [ -f file_T2w ]; then
  var1=existing file
fi
```

I'm reusing this code a lot and sometimes the `elif` statements get pretty long if have a longer list of preferential files we can walk through and I've long wanted to know if there was a more compact way to do this.

Comment: `I'm reusing this code a lot and sometimes the elif statements get pretty long` So write a function. I would go with the `ifelse` that you have - it's perfectly clear, readable and fast.

Comment: What about write a method?

Comment: will one of the files always exist? could you have a scenario where neither file exists?

Comment: Perhaps you should update the title to "variable that exists from many" or list or similar, as your quest here is to avoid "the elif statements get pretty long if I have a longer list of files"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash functions return only status code, so there is no return value to assign to a variable, like you do when using a standard programming language, like `var = get_file(file1 file2)`.

But you can define a function and have this convenient way

```
get_file var file1 file2 file3
```

which is short reusable code you could have in your scripts.

---

Doing a modification to @David Z's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64073191/7589636), your function can reference
the name of the first argument, and after shift, iterate for the rest of the arguments to test them. There is a pitfall here, see [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048#line-120), you have to avoid circular name reference, I would choose a variable name difficult to exist in the rest of your scripts.

```
function get_file() {
    declare -n get_file_var=$1
    shift
    for f; do
        if [ -f "$f" ]; then
            get_file_var="$f"
            return 0
        fi
    done
    return 1
}
```

The return status can be used to determine if any assignment happened.

```
get_file var file1 file2 file3
echo $?
echo $var
```

or this:

```
if get_file var file1 file2; then 
    echo var was assigned $var
else
    echo no file assigned # var can be empty string or keep its previous value
fi
```

You could also call it with an array:

```
arr=("missing filename" file1 file2)
get_file x "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: As this extended @David Z's answer I've chosen it as the solution but I'd like to thank everyone on this post for the clear answers with explanations. A function certainly seems like it will be of most use here but the options you have provided are much appreciated and I thank you all immensly.

Answer (score 2):

The most promising thing I can think of is a loop:

```
for f in file1 file2; do
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
        var="$f"
        break
    fi
done
```

You can shorten the code by using `&&` if you like, at the expense of supporting the `errexit` shell option. For just two files, the benefits of this approach are questionable, since it's about the same amount of code as the `if`/`elif` statement you already wrote, and it's probably marginally less clear what it's trying to do. But for many files this will be significantly more concise.

And as others have suggested, I think this is definitely a good thing to wrap up in a shell function. Keep in mind that variable assignments are not (necessarily) scoped to shell functions in bash, so you'll have no problem setting a variable from inside the function and using it elsewhere; however, you could also consider having the function print the name of the found file to standard output if that's more useful to you.

If you put this in a function, you can actually use the shell's built-in ability to loop over positional parameters, like this:

```
find_file() {
    for f; do
        if [ -f "$f" ]; then
            var="$f"
            return
        fi
    done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner (it works with 1 or more files as arguments):

```
var1=$( perl -MList::Util='first' -le 'print first { -f $_ } @ARGV;' xxx_T1w xxx_T2w )
```

Examples (note that if none of the listed files exist, `$var1` will be empty):

```
$ rm xxx_T1w
$ touch xxx_T2w
$ var1=$( perl -MList::Util='first' -le 'print first { -f $_ } @ARGV;' xxx_T1w xxx_T2w )
$ echo ${var1}
xxx_T2w
$ var1=$( perl -MList::Util='first' -le 'print first { -f $_ } @ARGV;' xxx_T2w xxx_T1w )
$ echo ${var1}                                                                          
xxx_T2w
$ var1=$( perl -MList::Util='first' -le 'print first { -f $_ } @ARGV;' xxx_T1w )        
$ echo ${var1}                                                                  

$
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-MList::Util='first'` : use module `List::Util`, and import from it subroutine `first`. This standard library module is included with your Perl distribution (nothing extra to install).

`@ARGV` : array of the command line arguments (here, files).

`print first { -f $_ } @ARGV;` : print the first of the files listed as arguments on the command line which exists AND which is a file (not a directory).

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlvar`: Perl predefined variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)
[`List::Util::first`](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#first)